# WakeLock GPS Android Java + Google maps

Tags: java, android

Trying to integrate GPS automatic tracker update but gets:

```
2018-10-03 19:06:45.256 1790-1861/? I/GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@587390b)
2018-10-03 19:06:45.256 1790-1803/? I/GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@587390b)
```

I get this when I try to Send new location to phone from emulator, virtual phone (Nexus). Have tried different Coords, and also restarting both Android studio, phone, and computer.

What I expect is the Log.d (tried them all), but that doesn't get output even if I run it in debug mode.

My code:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.d("Location: ", location.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

            return;
        }else{

        }

        //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng currentPositionVar = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPositionVar).title("You are here"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentPositionVar));
    }
}
```